# SQL Query to return ID, the office number and for each year if there is an invoice in that year for the employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to create a query to handle the following scenario. I have a office database, employee database with ID and a database table with sales invoices. I need to return a record for each employee for each year with yes or no, (1 or 0) if the person had an invoice in that year and the office number of the invoice.

I need to display the office number once per employee, with the year and an indicator for each year where there was an invoice.  Employees can be in multiple offices.

```
Office  Employee  Employee Name  Year1   Year2  Year3 Year4 Year5
12345   E5681718   Jane Smith       1       1      0    0      1
54321   E5681718   Jane Smith       1       0      0    1      0
```

I have tried several different things none work.  I am new to SQL so the reasoning behind what I am doing may not make sense at all.  I have tried using

```
;WITH
Employees AS (SELECT DISTINCT employeeID, OfficeNumber
FROM dbo.Employee
WHERE OfficeNumber IN ('12345', '78901', '54321')
AND employeeID IS NOT NULL
AND employeeID <> ' ')

, Invoices AS (
SELECT employeeID
CASE WHEN  COUNT(*) > '0'  AND i.adddate >= '2019-01-01'    THEN '1' else 
'0' END AS Inv2019 ,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > '0'  AND i.adddate BETWEEN '2018-01-01'  AND  '2019- 
01-01' THEN '1' else '0' END AS Inv2018 ,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > '0'  AND i.adddate BETWEEN '2017-01-01'  AND  '2018- 
01-01' THEN '1' else '0' END AS Inv2017 ,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > '0'  AND i.adddate BETWEEN '2016-01-01'  AND  '2017- 
01-01'  THEN '1' else '0' END AS Inv2016,
FROM Invoices i
WHERE  employeeID IS NOT NULL
 AND employeeID <> ' '
GROUP BY employeeID ,  AddDate)

SELECT e.OfficeNumber, e.employeeID, iv.Inv2018, iv.Inv2017, iv.Inv2016
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoices iv ON p.PreparerID = pr.PreparerID
GROUP BY e.OfficeNumber, iv.employeeID, iv.Inv2018, iv.Inv2017, iv.Inv2016
```

---

Also tried pulling for each year using 'Having'

```
;WITH
Employees AS (SELECT DISTINCT employeeID, OfficeNumber
FROM dbo.Employee
WHERE OfficeNumber IN ('12345', '78901', '54321')
AND employeeID IS NOT NULL
AND employeeID <> ' ')

,Inv19 AS (SELECT DISTINCT employeeID, OfficeNumber , YEAR(adddate) Inv19
FROM Invoices i
WHERE adddate BETWEEN '2019-01-01'  AND   GETDATE()
AND employeeID IS NOT NULL
AND employeeID <> ' '
GROUP BY employeeID,  OfficeNumber, AddDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > '0')

,Inv18 AS (SELECT DISTINCT employeeID, OfficeNumber , YEAR(adddate) Inv18
FROM Invoices i
 WHERE adddate BETWEEN adddate BETWEEN '2018-01-01'  AND '2019-01-01' 
AND employeeID IS NOT NULL
AND employeeID<> ' '
GROUP BY employeeID,  OfficeNumber, AddDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > '0'
)
,Inv17 AS (SELECT DISTINCT employeeID, OfficeNumber , YEAR(adddate) Inv17
FROM Invoices i
 WHERE adddate BETWEEN '2017-01-01'  AND   '2018-01-01'
AND employeeID IS NOT NULL
AND employeeID<> ' '
GROUP BY employeeID,  OfficeNumber, AddDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > '0'
)

Select e.employeeID, e.OfficeNumber , Inv19, Inv18, Inv17
from Employees e
Left outer join Inv19 i9 on e.employeeID = i9.employeeID
Left outer join Inv18 i8 on e.employeeID = i8.employeeID
Left outer join Inv17 i7 on e.employeeID = i7.employeeID
```

This was my latest attempt but I get multiple rows per employee even when it is the same office.

Comment: Hi GrangerG, please can you correct this line: WHERE adddate BETWEEN adddate BETWEEN '2018-01-01'  AND '2019-01-01'. Others will help you more easily if you do it. Thanks!

Comment: @GrangerG . . . Sample data would really help.

Comment: for how many years you want to show ?

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.employeeID, e.OfficeNumber, e.employeeName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.add_date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inv_2019,
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.add_date) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inv_2018,
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.add_date) = 2017 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inv_2017,
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.add_date) = 2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inv_2016,
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.add_date) = 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inv_2015
FROM dbo.Employee e LEFT JOIN
     invoices i
     ON i.employeeID = e.employeeID
WHERE e.OfficeNumber IN ('12345', '78901', '54321') AND
      e.employeeID <> ' '  -- handles NULL values
GROUP BY e.employeeID, e.OfficeNumber, e.employeeName
```